# Range Query - Range Update

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, tree

[image: Problem Statement]

In most of the range query-update questions, we are asked to update some range of the array with some `constant_value` which can be done using the segment-tree approach. For more optimizations we can use the segment-tree with lazy propagation approach.

But in this question, we are asked to update given range with some given series. In which I faced some difficulties with lazy propagation approach like:

1. How to keep track of consecutive updates.
2. If we store some `update_value` to some `parent-node`, but when we propagate this update to its children, how to determine which child contributed what part of the `update_value`.

---

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define MOD 1000000007

list <int>lazy[3600020];
int tree[3600020],n,q,i,x,y;
short choice;

inline int M(long long x)
{
    if(x%3)
        return (((((x+1)*(x+2)/3)%MOD)*x)%MOD);
    return ((((x*(x+1)/3)%MOD)*(x+2))%MOD);
}

inline void update_node_lazy(int node,int a,int b)
{
    while(!lazy[node].empty())
    {
        tree[node] = (tree[node] + M(b-lazy[node].front()+1) - M(a-lazy[node].front()))%MOD;
        if(a != b)
        {
            lazy[2*node].push_front(lazy[node].front());
            lazy[2*node+1].push_front(lazy[node].front());
        }
        lazy[node].pop_front();
    }
}

inline void update_tree_lazy(int node, int a, int b, int i, int j)
{
    update_node_lazy(node,a,b);
    if(a>b || a>j || b<i)
        return;
    if(a >= i && b <= j)
    {
        tree[node] = (tree[node] + M(b-i+1) - M(a-i))%MOD;
        if(a != b)
        {
            lazy[2*node].push_front(i);
            lazy[2*node+1].push_front(i);
        }
        return;
    }
    update_tree_lazy(node*2, a, (a+b)/2, i, j);
    update_tree_lazy(1+node*2, 1+(a+b)/2, b, i, j);
    tree[node] = (tree[node*2] + tree[node*2+1])%MOD;
}

inline int query_tree_lazy(int node, int a, int b, int i, int j)
{
    if(a > b || a > j || b < i)
        return 0;
    update_node_lazy(node,a,b);
    if(a >= i && b <= j)
        return tree[node];
    return (query_tree_lazy(node*2, a, (a+b)/2, i, j) + query_tree_lazy(1+node*2, 1+(a+b)/2, b, i, j))%MOD;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> q;
    while(q--)
    {
        cin >> choice >> x >> y;
        if(choice == 1)
            update_tree_lazy(1,0,n-1,x-1,y-1);
        else
            printf("%d\n",query_tree_lazy(1,0,n-1,x-1,y-1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this approach didn't help much, so I need a better approach or some optimization suggestions.

Comment: Please consider replacing the image with text, in case the image link dies.